# How to remove the back button in the header react native

Tags: react-native

I want to remove the button back, but leave the header.

[image]

My component is as follows. I want to leave the title, and I don’t need the back button.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';


export const TrucksScreen = () => {
    return (
        <View>
           ....
        </View>
    );
});

TrucksScreen.navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: 'Trucks Screen',
};
```

How can I remove the button back?

Comment: <Stack.Screen name='Home' component={Home} options={{ headerLeft: null}}/>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `headerLeft: null` will be deprecated in future versions.

Instead use a function like so :

```
TrucksScreen.navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: 'Trucks Screen',
    headerLeft: () => {
      return null;
    },
};
```

Cheers !

Answer (score 2):

set  **headerLeft: null** in the navigation Options. and this will remove the back button from the head as I did in the **last line of code**.

```
 import React from 'react';
    import { View } from 'react-native';

    export const TrucksScreen = () => {
        return (
            <View>
               ....
            </View>
        );
    });

    TrucksScreen.navigationOptions = {
        headerTitle: 'Trucks Screen',
        headerLeft: null,
    };
```

I hope it will help. Ask for doubts

Answer (score 1):

```
Home: {
screen: HomeScreen,
navigationOptions: {
  headerLeft: null,
       
}
```

}

try setting  **headerLeft: null**

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs you can replace the header back button with whatever you want by passing options param in stack navigator . Do find the working example : [expo-snack](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=header%20button&dependencies=%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40%5E0.1.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%40%5E5.0.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%40%5E5.0.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%40%5E5.0.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%40%5E5.0.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%40%5E5.0.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative-stack%40%5E5.0.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%40%5E5.0.1%2Creact-native-gesture-handler%401.5.2%2Creact-native-reanimated%401.4.0%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%400.6.0%2Creact-native-screens%402.0.0-alpha.12&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F5.x%2Fsimple-header-button.js):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, Image } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function LogoTitle() {
  return (
    <Image
      style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}
      source={require('@expo/snack-static/react-native-logo.png')}
    />
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{
            headerTitle: props => <LogoTitle {...props} />,
            headerRight: () => (
              <Button
                onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
                title="Info"
                color="#00cc00"
              />
            ),
          }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Hopeit helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: This works, but the back button remains. I want to remove her

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Image, Text } from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import style from '../../../utils/style';
import images from '../../../images/images';

class Header extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }


    onRightIconPress = () => {
        if (this.props.onRightIconPress) {
            this.props.onRightIconPress();
        }
    };

    render() {
        const { title, navigation, showBackIcon, showRightIcon, rightIcon } = this.props;

        return (
            <View style={style.headerrowcontainer}>
                {/* Back  Button*/}
                {showBackIcon ? (
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
                        <Image resizeMode="contain" source={images.iconback} style={style.backimage} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                ) : (
                    <View />
                )}
                {/* Title */}
                <Text style={style.titleheader}>{title}</Text>
                {/* Right Icon */}
                {showRightIcon ? (
                    <Image name={rightIcon} style={style.rightIcon} onPress={this.onRightIconPress} />
                ) : (
                    <View />
                )}
            </View>
        );
    }
}

Header.defaultProps = {
    title: '',
};
Header.propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string,
};
export default Header;
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work in RN6.

TrucksScreen.navigationOptions = {
headerTitle: 'Trucks Screen',
headerLeft: () => {
return null;
},
};

Answer (score 0):

```
  <Stack.Screen
    options={{ headerShown: true, title: "",headerBackVisible: false}}
  />
```

It's working for me